# JavaScript variable that behaves like a function

Tags: javascript, lazy-evaluation, getter

Is it possible to create a variable that is linked to a function and executes this function every time the variable is being read? A use case would be updated language translations when the call to a certain translation already happened (returning a translation string which might change in future). This is kind of similar to `get`ter methods of a class, but without actually defining a class.

Any idea how this could be done (if at all)?

Comment: Just hide the value inside the function, returning it when called?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to hijack 'getter' functionality to do whatever you want, and the "class" syntax is not required, like `let myThing = { get myVar() { /*Check sports scores here */}`

Comment: Even though it's possible... I suspect doing this would later result in a debugging nightmare. Reading a getter and having different results each time is understandable, but I would definitely scratch my head if I get a different value every time I read a local variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to do this

```js
Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop', { // adding to whatever "this" context is
  get: () => Math.random()
})

console.info('prop get #1', prop)
console.info('prop get #2', prop)
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. Any caveats other than that it's nonintuitive?

Comment: What you're asking for is non-intuitive anyway ;)

Comment: I know - that's not a caveat for me and wasn't meant as criticism ;-).

Comment: One thing I noticed is that I can't pass the reference to this variable disguised as a function to another variable without triggering evaluation (i.e. a call of `get()`), but it's hard to differentiate those two cases as they are both using `=` as in `otherProp = prop`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take advantage of the fact the `global` object can have properties defined on it that are implicitly in-scope. In a web-browser the `Window` object is the `global` object, so this:

```
<script>
var foo = 123;

function bar() { console.log( foo ) };
bar();
</script>
```

Is the same as this:

```
<script>
document.window.foo = 123;

function bar() { console.log( foo ) };
bar();
</script>
```

Is (more-or-less) the same as this:

```
<script>
Object.defineProperty( window, "foo", { value: 123 } );

function bar() { console.log( foo ) };
bar();
</script>
```

So we can abuse [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to get the effect you want, with the caveat that it won't work inside JavaScript scopes where `global`'s properties are not accessible.

```
<script>
function createMagicVariable( name, func ) {

    var propDef = {
        get: func
    };
    Object.defineProperty( window, name, propDef );
}
</script>
```

Used like so:

```
<script>

function getRandom() { return Math.random(); }

createMagicVariable( 'foo', getRandom );

console.log( foo );
console.log( foo );
console.log( foo );

</script>
```